# What percentage of users participated on each day (SQL Query)

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have the following table (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b72f3/1) which has all the "registered activities" for each user.

What I'm looking to find out is - what percentage of users participated on every single day.

In addition, I'd like to get the average for each day of the competition - so the average % of users who participated on every single date.

I'm a bit stuck with this one - tried grouping by date and userid but no luck so far.

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT date(time),
       count(distinct userid) / cd.cnt
FROM activity_entries ae join
     (select count(distinct userid) as cnt
      from activity_entries) cd
GROUP BY date(time);
```

It uses a subquery to calculate the total distinct users in the table and then divides the number of users on each day to get the proportion.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mind giving it a go in the SqLfiddle I provided? Can't seem to get it to work with the WHERE competitionid = '52736be97b706' clause in there. In which query should I use the WHERE?

Comment: Also - would it be possible to get an average for all the days for that competition?

Comment: @user2656127 . . . I did test it in SQL Fiddle.  It seems to work fine.

Comment: Yep works well. One more thing I would love help with is - I'm trying to put a WHERE clause into the query to limit the results to one competition. I can't seem to get the syntax right. Do I need the WHERE  inside the subquery or outside? Could you help there?

Comment: You need the where clause both in the subquery and in the outer query.

Comment: Does this look OK to you? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b72f3/11 Thanks for all the help Gordon