# Finding percentage from count by category on a specific day

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a hypothetical problem I created from the following sql problem http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef1f32f/15 that I stumbled upon, 
which, by itself is a modified version of http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1b72f3/1

I am trying to find the percentage of people who were active during a specific day and group them by location.

I am noob learning sql subqueries.

Here is some code I modified from [What percentage of users participated on each day (SQL Query)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21220038/what-percentage-of-users-participated-on-each-day-sql-query).

Here is sample data:

```
|id     |activity_typeid|   competitionid|  userid| time| activity_weight| location

22  2151    52736be97b706   421     2013-11-04T08:30:38Z    2   SF

1951    2151    52736be97b706   231     2013-11-01T09:05:22Z    2   LA

1961    2151    52736be97b706   241     2013-11-01T09:07:30Z    2   LA
```

Please check the rest in the sqlfiddle link.

```sql
SELECT date(time) as typical_day, location,
       count(distinct userid) as counting,
       count(distinct userid) / sum(cnt) * 100 percentage
FROM activity_entries ae join
     (select count(distinct userid) as cnt
      from activity_entries) cd
      where date(time) = '2013-11-01'
GROUP BY location;
```

I was able to get the percentage as 33.3, 20 and 50 for LA, OK and SF. However,the expected percentage should be 37.5, 37.5 and 25.

I am not sure what is missing from my code.

I have spent a few hours trying to figure out, but to no avail. Please help me with this, don't close the question.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you get the values that you expect.  But if you want the proportion of *all* users, then the `sum(cnt)` is throwing you off.  The query should look more like this:

```
SELECT date(time) as typical_day, activityname, cnt,
       count(distinct userid) as counting,
       count(distinct userid) / cnt * 100 percentage
FROM activity_entries ae CROSS JOIN
     (select count(distinct userid) as cnt
      from activity_entries) cd
WHERE date(time) = '2013-11-01'
GROUP BY date(time), activityname, cnt;
```

If you want the proportion of users on a *given* day, then:

```
SELECT date(ae.time) as typical_day, ae.activityname, cd.cnt,
       count(distinct ae.userid) as counting,
       count(distinct ae.userid) / cd.cnt * 100 percentage
FROM activity_entries ae JOIN
     (SELECT date(time) as date,
             COUNT(distinct userid) as cnt
      FROM activity_entries
      GROUP BY date(time)
     ) cd
     ON date(ae.time) = cd.date
WHERE date(ae.time) = '2013-11-01'
GROUP BY date(ae.time), ae.activityname, cd.cnt;
```

Comment: I am trying to sum the counts that were grouped by activity name. The above query you wrote sums the all the unique userid's, but I want to limit the sum of the userid's by that particular day. In other words let's say, I want to calculate the percentage of active users in a particular day grouped by activityname. I tried to modify the query, but it wasn't successful as it gave me errors when I want to limit the count by day. Can you please tweak the query to result a percentage of 37.5%, 37.5% and 25% for LA, OK and SF?

Comment: Gordon on a specific day, I want to find the percentage of user activities  from each activityname. I want to divide the unique user id by the total unique user id in that day. I tried including sum to the count clause but it is giving me a different answer. Is there something I am missing during aggregation?

Comment: @G1124E . . . The second query should be doing that.  Because users can participate in more than one activity, the total is more than 100%.

Comment: Ohhh! The total sum can be more than 100% makes sense. I was wondering if we need to have another `group by` at the end of the statement as we are only focusing on only specific date. I removed it on sqlfiddle and it didn't make a difference. I guess it is redundant.

Comment: I was trying to solve a slightly different question that gives a sum of 100%. Say, the activityname is replaced by device the user registered (regdev) and we want to find out the aggregate by device registered. Will we still be using the second query? I think the total should be 100%, shouldn't it?